# How to get payment (price and currency) info of purchased product by google play api

Tags: c#, google-play-developer-api

I'm using google play developer API, so after user buy a product I want to get the details of that purchase in my server side, so I use google play developer api to get that information but unfortunately, the API doesn't return any information that how much the user paid (price and currency)
the API just return the following info

```
{
  "kind": "androidpublisher#productPurchase",
  "purchaseTimeMillis": long,
  "purchaseState": integer,
  "consumptionState": integer,
  "developerPayload": string,
  "orderId": string,
  "purchaseType": integer
}
```

How can I get the price of purchased products through google play api?

Comment: What endpoint are you calling?

Comment: `Purchases.products: get` but if I should call another endpoint please let me know.

Comment: @SiyavashKhojasteh did you find the answer?